# PhoneGap Android AngularJS routing not working

Tags: android, angularjs

I have been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out why angularJS routing won't work in phonegap for me. Plase find the code.

```
$scope.userType = function(userType) {

    $scope.user.userType = userType;
    storageService.setGuestUser($scope.user);
    $location.path('/sign-up/info');    
};
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error. While debugging APK I got the message like 'BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility()'